# Swift dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: swift3

I'm attempting to parse a dictionary of type [String: Any], and I'm unable parse dictionaries within this dictionary as I would expect:

```
var monsterDictionary = Dictionary<String, Any>()

monsterDictionary["stringTest"] = "I'm a string"
monsterDictionary["numberTest"] = "12345"
monsterDictionary["arrayTest"] = [1,3,4,"five"]
monsterDictionary["dictTest"] = ["key for number": 123.2 , "key for string" : "hello"]
monsterDictionary["foo-values"] = ["foo-type": foo.FooValueType.fooValuePercent, "foo-value": 25]


for fooItem in (monsterDictionary["foo-values"] as! [String: Any])
{
    let fooType = fooItem["tip-type"]
```

The last assignment generates the following error: "Type '(key: String, value: Any) has no subscript members."

Comment: Your data structure is very odd. Will it always contain these exact same keys?

Comment: No, it's for testing different dictionary entry types. Only "foo-values" causes me any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating over a `Dictionary` yields Key/Value tuples.

If you actually need to iterate over all the keys/values, then you can do so like this:

```
for (key, value) in (monsterDictionary["foo-values"] as! [String: Any]) {
    print(key, value)
}
```

If you're just looking to get the value for `tip-type`, then you can just do this:

```
let fooValues = (monsterDictionary["foo-values"] as! [String: Any])
let fooType = ["tip-type"] as! foo.FooValueType
```

Comment: It only yields tuples if you haven't specified the key, I thought. 

for fooItem in (monsterDictionary["foo-values"] should yield:
["foo-type": foo.FooValueType.fooValuePercent, "foo-value": 25]

as opposed to yielding
("foo-values", ["foo-type": foo.FooValueType.fooValuePercent, "foo-value": 25])

Am I mistaken?

Comment: Subscripting yields `["foo-type": foo.FooValueType.fooValuePercent, "foo-value": 25]`, but you're then iterating over that result in the for loop, getting `("foo-type", foo.FooValueType.fooValuePercent)` and `("foo-value", 25)` tuples

Comment: I was confused by the Objective C equivalent that I was translating:

for (NSDictionary *foo in [MonsterDictionary objectForKey:@"foo-values"]) {
        Foo *fooObject = [[Foo alloc] initWithFooType:(FooValueType)[[foo objectForKey:@"tip-type"] integerValue] Value:[foo objectForKey:@"foo-value"]];

Comment: @jglasse Why would you do that in a loop at all?

Comment: @jglasse So reevaluate things like before you convert them over

Comment: Fair point - I frankly just got a little lost in the nested dictionaries.

Comment: @jglasse This is why it's best to avoid them, along with avoid "Any", wherever structs or objects would work better

Comment: As it turns out, the loop is there because it's an array of dictionaries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135228/discussion-between-alexander-and-jglasse).